# Determine Days Not Covered Based on Fields Containing "From" and "To" Dates

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

**Server**: Microsoft SQL Server

**SQLFiddle**: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/cdfa3/1/0

If I have rows containing a "start" date and an "end date", how can write a SQL query that will list the days that are not contained between those dates.

Example (see SQLFiddle link above for a playable demo):

```
startdate                  enddate
2019-06-06 00:00:00.000    2019-06-08 00:00:00.000
2019-06-10 00:00:00.000    2019-06-11 00:00:00.000
2019-06-12 00:00:00.000    2019-06-13 00:00:00.000
```

We have a coverage gap on June 9th, because we have coverage from June 6th-June 8th, then on June 10th-June 13th.

How is it possible to identify the date of June 9th as having no coverage based on rows that have date ranges?

Comment: Do you have a date table to compare to?

Comment: Use a date table and join to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use generated calendar table and `LEFT JOIN`:

```
DECLARE @min DATE, @max DATE;
SELECT @min = MIN(workingdatestart), @max = MAX(workingdateend) FROM workingdates;

WITH cte AS (
  SELECT DATEADD(DAY, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY 1/0), @min) AS d
  FROM sys.objects s, sys.objects s2
)
SELECT c.d AS gap
FROM cte c
LEFT JOIN workingdates w ON c.d BETWEEN w.workingdatestart and w.workingdateend
WHERE c.d < @max AND w.workingDateId IS NULL;
```

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=1cb16a57767f18360481dda3e6bcb3f2)**

Comment: Thank you @Lukasz, this seems to be exactly what I was looking for. I didn't imagine a simple yet elegant solution existed to this problem.

Comment: can this be easily modified to select on another column? If we want to show, say, only gaps where Bob is not working, how can we do that? I updated a db<>fiddle here: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=9890adfb759d3d91c9680c9371660140

Comment: For example, the following db<>fiddle to add another column on the WHERE statement doesn't work because the JOIN type isn't correct, or we have to add something else:
https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=1660ead3425432d3e30eb6310a7f9305

Comment: @Beems You need to extend the condition `ON`: [db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=3f444021103b0249a2aaf8e4873497cd)

Answer (score 1):

@Lukasz Szozda stole my thunder. My answer is similar but does not use variables (I'm not suggesting that's good or bad.. just calling it out).

You can create a calendar table function (see example below) then perform a `LEFT ANTI SEMI JOIN` against your working days table. The benefit to this solution is the calendar table generates 0 IO.

**Solution:**

```
WITH r(L,H) AS
(
  SELECT CAST(MIN(w.workingdatestart) AS DATE), CAST(MAX(w.workingdateend) AS DATE)
  FROM dbo.workingdates AS w
),
cal AS
(
  SELECT c.Dt
  FROM   r
  CROSS APPLY dbo.calendar(r.L,r.H) AS c
)
SELECT c.Dt
FROM   cal AS c
EXCEPT
SELECT c.Dt
FROM   cal AS c
JOIN   dbo.workingdates AS w 
  ON c.Dt BETWEEN w.workingdatestart AND w.workingdateend;
```

.. and the function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.calendar(@startdate DATE, @enddate DATE)
RETURNS TABLE WITH SCHEMABINDING AS RETURN
WITH E1(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM (VALUES (1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)) AS x(x)),
 iTally(N) AS 
(
  SELECT 0 UNION ALL
  SELECT TOP (DATEDIFF(DAY,@startDate,@endDate)) ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) 
  FROM E1 a, E1 b, E1 c
)
SELECT sortKey = i.N, Dt = DATEADD(DAY, i.N, @startDate)
FROM iTally AS i;
```

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this you need a table that contains all dates between your minimal and maximal dates. Then just filter rows that don't exist in `workingdates`  using `LEFT JOIN`.

```
declare @minDate date = (select min([workingdatestart]) from [workingdates])
declare @maxDate date = (select max([workingdateend]) from [workingdates])
declare @Date date = @minDate
create table #rangeOfDates (dat date)

while @Date <= @maxDate
begin 
    insert into #rangeOfDates values (@Date)
    set @Date = dateadd(day , 1, @Date)
end

select r.dat
from #rangeOfDates as r
left join  workingdates as w
    on r.dat between w.workingdatestart and w.workingdateend
where w.workingdateID is null
```

Result:

```
dat
2019-06-09
```

Comment: No, no, no... While loops in SQL for this kind of thing will be slower than a herd of three-legged turtles crossing a wide street made out of peanut butter! Set based is the way to go. See: https://www.itprotoday.com/sql-server/sequential-set-based